# Set value of unbound control from record in subform

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a main form with three unbound controls.  The first is a primary key that is automatically populated from an onClick event in another form.  This is the parent/child link to a subform bound to a SQL table.  The other two unbound fields in the main form are the DataObs and DataRec fields which are comboboxes.  I have used an AfterUpdate Event procedure to loop through all records in the subform to populate the corresponding field, Data_observer and Data_recorder, respectively.  I am trying to figure out a way to write an Event procedure that will populate the unbound DataObs and DataRec comboboxes if there are already entries in the subform's recordset.

Here was an attempt I made, that threw an error:

```
Private Sub DataRec_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Set rs = Me!subfrm.Form.RecordsetClone
If Not rs.BOF Then
rs.MoveLast
rs.MoveFirst
End If
If Not IsNull(rs!Data_recorder.Value) Then
Me.DataRec.Value = '" & rs!Data_recorder.Value & "'
End If
rs.close
Set rs = Nothing
End Sub
```

Here's a screenshot of the form as I currently have it to help illustrate how it is structured.
[image: Screenshot of form]

And here is the current VBA I am using to loop through the records to update the Data_observer and Data_recorder columns in the subform.

```
Option Compare Database

Private Sub DataObs_AfterUpdate()
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Set rs = Me!subfrm.Form.RecordsetClone
If Not rs.BOF Then
rs.MoveLast
rs.MoveFirst
End If

While Not rs.EOF
    rs.Edit
    rs!Data_observer.Value = Me.DataObs.Value
    rs.Update
    rs.MoveNext
Wend
rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing
Me.subfrm.Form.Data_observer.DefaultValue = """" & Me.DataObs.Value & """"
Me.Dirty = False
End Sub

Private Sub DataRec_AfterUpdate()
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Set rs = Me!subfrm.Form.RecordsetClone

If Not rs.BOF Then
rs.MoveLast
rs.MoveFirst
End If

While Not rs.EOF
    rs.Edit
    rs!Data_recorder.Value = Me.DataRec.Value
    rs.Update
    rs.MoveNext
Wend
rs.Close

Set rs = Nothing
Me.subfrm.Form.Data_recorder.DefaultValue = """" & Me.DataRec.Value & """"
Me.Dirty = False
End Sub
Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer)
Me.TransectOID = Me.OpenArgs
End Sub
```

Any guidance would be much appreciated.

Comment: What error and which line triggers? What purpose do these unbound controls serve? Is main form unbound? Programmatically setting value of unbound control will show the same value for all records. Why do you need code to update data of subform as opposed to normal data entry? Posting second code snip might be too much info and just misdirecting.

Comment: If these unbound comboboxes are used for input of search criteria to filter subform, why is it necessary to programmatically set value of either of these two controls? And why do you use inputs to modify filtered records - wouldn't they already have these values? None of what you describe is making sense.

Comment: Thanks for your reply June7. I get runtime error 2115 "The macro or function set to the BeforeUpdate or Validation Rule property for this field is preventing the database from saving the data in the field. This form is meant to enter field data into a SQL database.  Each form will only have one data observer and one data recorder, but each record (and there are usually >30 per form) must have a values of data observer and data recorder.  I set this loop up to ensure that all records get those values. I'll continue in the next comment.

Comment: The line that throws the error is `Me.DataRec.Value = """" & rs!Data_recorder.Value & """"`  I wonder if it's just a matter of messing up the string concatenation code.  The SQL table this form is linked to has a check constraint that only allows four values.  Looking at this again, I seem to get an extra unnecessary set of quotes.  The main form is unbound and the subform is bound to a linked SQL table.  The unbound comboboxes are not for filtering, but rather for data entry.  I want to populate the unbound combobox if the subform's data observer and data recorder field are already filled.

Comment: So how is form opened to correct set of records? The doubled quotes are fine. I prefer to use apostrophe `Me.DataRec.Value = "'" & rs!Data_recorder.Value & "'"`, although if there is possibility of apostrophe in data (O'Brien) there would be an issue. Might want to post in a forum that allows attaching files and provide db for analysis.

Comment: This form/subform opens from another form entitled "frmTransect"  Here, the user inputs the experimental treatment, plot, and transect that she/he/they want to enter data for.  Based on that input, and an AfterUpdate event procedure retrieves the corresponding unique Identifier for that transect.  That unique identifier gets passed to an unbound text box in the main form called "TransectOID" (I just realized it is hidden in my screenshot) via OpenArgs.  TransectOID is the parent/child link between the main form and the subform

Comment: Then should be able to use the main form's Open event to get values from subform and set comboboxes, if there are any values. If not, then comboboxes will just be Null. Try combobox AfterUpdate to set value of other combobox, not BeforeUpdate.

Comment: Taking my code and putting it into a `Form_Open` command solved the issue.  Thanks June7!!